# The sum of оbtuse angles of а convex polygon is $2013^\circ$. How many sides does it have?

Tags: geometry, polygons, convex-geometry

> The sum of оbtuse angles of а convex polygon is $2013^\circ$.
>   How many sides does it have?

I haven't seen a fоrmula that express this kind of relationship. Can you give me some points?

Comment: Does a $90^\circ$ angle count as obtuse?

Comment: What do you mean by "obtuse angles" of a polygon? What is the sum of angles of a triangle?

Comment: I think that we count angles that are larger than $90^\circ$.

Comment: @Samos:  In junior high school we learned that the sum of the (interior) angles of a triangle (even an obtuse one) is $360^\circ$.  Why do you ask?

Comment: I am not sure I understant what you're talking about. We have a polynot, not a triangle.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You mean to say $180^\circ$?

Comment: Oops... yes.  But my question remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum of the exterior angles of a convex polygon is $360^\circ$. Since each acute angle contributes more than $90^\circ$ to this count, there can’t be more than $3$ of them. This implies that the total sum of the angles of the polygon is between $2013^\circ$ and $2283^\circ$.

However, the sum of the angles of a convex polygon is always a multiple of $180^\circ$ – more specifically, it’s given by $$S=(n-2)180^\circ,$$ where $n$ is the number of sides on the polygon. The only way this is possible is if $S=2160^\circ$ and $n=\boxed{14}$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Why the sum is between $2013^\circ$ and $2292^\circ$?

Comment: @gixide7609 Since the sum must of the acute angles must be at most $3\cdot90^\circ$, and the sum of the obtuse angles is already $2013^\circ$.

Comment: $2013+3\cdot 90$, right?

Comment: @gixide7609 Precisely.

Comment: Isn't this equal to $2283$?

Comment: @gixide7609 You’re absolutely right, let me fix this quickly.